# Typewriter Effect on a list

Tags: python, list, sys, effect

I am making the base of a game, and for the intro, I need it to print out like a typewriter. When I call it as multiple, it prints out the whole object, rather than slowly printing it out, like a typewriter would

```
import random
import sys
from time import sleep

test_list = ['obj 1', 'obj 2']

def writer(text, multi = True):
    if multi == True:
        obj = 0
        for item in text:
            sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.write(text[obj])
            
            obj += 1
            sys.stdout.flush()
    
    else:
        for char in text:
            sleep(0.05)
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()

writer(test_list)
```

Comment: You're calling `writer(test_lists)`, but the variable is actually named `test_list`, not `test_lists`.  This is clearly not your real code.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Thats not it, I changed the code, to make it simpler, there is 1 list, and a string, the original list has a lot of objects

Comment: If you're not willing to update the question to contain your real actual code, then good luck to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"for char in item" added, "obj" removed, "sys.stdout.write('\n')" added for pretty printer.

**Code:**

```
import random
import sys
from time import sleep

test_list = ['obj 1', 'obj 2']

def writer(text, multi=True):
    if multi:
        for item in text:
            for char in item:
                sleep(0.5)  # <= adjust how many secs to wait for
                sys.stdout.write(char)
                sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write('\n')  
    else:
        for char in text:
            sleep(1)   # <= adjust how many secs to wait for
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write('\n')  

writer(test_list)
```

Comment: What did you change and why did it solve the problem?

Comment: I updated the post with what I did. I realized that we answered it (with the other user) at the same time.

Comment: Why did removing `obj` add a typewriter effect?

Answer (score 0):

you miss inner for with each symbol in string - `for char in item:`

```
import random
import sys
from time import sleep

test_lists = ['obj 1', 'obj 2']


def writer(text, multi = True):
    if multi == True:
        obj = 0
        for item in text:
            for char in item:
                
                sys.stdout.write(char)
                obj += 1
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sleep(1)
                
    
    else:
        for char in text:
            sleep(0.05)
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()

writer(test_lists)
```